# Nestjs - Validating and Converting Query params

Tags: nestjs, class-validator, class-transformer

I have defined a DTO to validate and convert incoming query params.

```js
export class ScrollingDto {
    @ApiPropertyOptional({
        description: 'Number of items to skip',
        default: 0,
        nullable: true
    })
    @IsOptional()
    @Type(() => Number)
    @IsInt()
    skip?: number;

    @ApiPropertyOptional({
        description: 'Number of items to take',
        example: 20,
        nullable: true
    })
    @IsOptional()
    @Type(() => Number)
    @IsInt()
    take?: number;
}
```

And I've added the global validation pipe in `main.ts`.

```js
app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe({ transform: true }));
```

But it returns Bad Request error - `skip must be an integer number` with this query:

```
/api/blog/search?skip=0
```

**Controller**

```js
@Controller('blog')
export class BlogController {
    constructor() {}

    @Get('search')
    searchBlogs(@Query() query: ScrollingDto) {
        ...
    }
}
```

I am not sure what I did wrong here. Hope to get any help on this.

**Update**

The `ScrollingDTO` is imported from a third-party library which is installed as a node module. If I just bring the class inside my app, then it works.

Comment: Can you paste your controller and your entire query ?

Comment: Yes, I've updated my question.

Comment: Let me know if the linked thread does not help. :-)

Comment: Hi @KimKern, It's similar but it's not related to that. I am already using the correct decorators in the DTO class but it didnt work in the controller. One missing detail in the description though, the DTO class is imported from a third party library.

Comment: I think `@Transform(id => parseInt(id))` might be missing. This is the relevant part of the linked answer. Have you tried that?